# ftp (CLI) works but Explorer, Internet Explorer and Chrome fail to display IIS6 ftp: site

Tags: iis-6, ftp

I have an ftp site set setup using IIS6 that works fine using the Windows command line `ftp`, but when using Explorer (Web Folders), Internet Explorer 8, or Chrome 10 on a different machine, after asking for the username and pasword it times out.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically Explorer, IE and Chrome will use a passive FTP connections, whereas the CLI FTP client that you are using is connecting with an "active" FTP connection.

[A good read on active and passive FTP can be found here.](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)

So it sounds like your FTP server is not accepting the pasive connection, thus the client (Exploer, IE, or Chrome) are timing out.

To support pasive FTP you might need to adjust your firewall rules. Active uses ports 21 and 20 on the server, however passive uses 21 and a random port > 1023 on the server. Your firewall might be blocking this so that is where I would check first.

Does the same behaviour happen to a client on the same network subnet as the server? Have your tried using IE on the local server to connect to itself? If either of these work then it sounds like a firewall issue.